# How do I set up Hellium in a closed network

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am using apache zeppelin in a closed network. How do I set up to use hellium in a closed network?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you need a Zeppelin instance with access to the internet.
Install on that instance desired Helium packages.

Then copy to main instance

- file `./conf/helium.json`
- directories `./local-repo/helium-bundle/bundles/*`